# Can one find a finitely generated group $G$ and an epimorphism from $G$ onto the group $(\mathbb Q,+)$?

Tags: group-theory

My answer is below and I am not so sure about it.

No. $\mathbb Q$ is not finetely generated. So since homomorphism preserves the generators, because $G\to \mathbb Q $ is onto, then $\mathbb Q$ must be finitely generated. Contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is correct, although for full marks you may be required to prove that

1. $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is not finitely generated, and
2. homomorphic images of finitely generated groups are themselves finitely generated,

rather than pull these facts out of the hat :-)